# How to infer the type of a property based on another property

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get a property to infer its types based on the value of its sibling property. For example, I have two types, a `Base` type and an `Extended` type. There are some properties in the `Base` type that also exists in the `Extended` type.

```
type Base = {
  key1: string;
  key2: string;
  key3: string;
}

type Extended = {
  key1: { prop1: string; prop2: string };
  key2: { prop1: string };
}
```

Now, I have another type `Test` that has two properties, the `name` and `value`. If the `name` property is one of the keys in the `Extended` type, the `value` property should be the keys associated to the type in the `Extended` type, else, the `value` property should not be passed. This is what I've made so far.

```
type Test<T = keyof (Base & Extended)> = {
  name: T;
  value?: T extends keyof Extended ? (keyof Extended[T])[] : never
}

const test: Test = {
  name: 'key1',
  value: ['']
}
```

However, this does not work. Whatever `name` prop you pass still allows you to input both `prop1` and `prop2` string literals. The case should be that if the `name` is `'key1'`, it should be able to accept an optional array of strings, and the strings should be the properties defined in the `Extended` type. Moreover, if the `name` is `key3`, the `value` property should never exist.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Your description of the `Test` type does not mention `Base` at all. Is `Base` irrelevant?

Comment: There are properties in the `Base` type that does not exist in the `Extended` type, but the `name` property can be from both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if understood correctly. Does this meet your requirements:

```
type Test2<T = keyof (Base & Extended)> = T extends keyof Extended ? {
  name: T;
  value?: (keyof Extended[T])[]
} : {
  name: T
}
```

Comment: I have to admit that I can not fully explain why your solution does not work. If anyone knows, please add a better answer. I'd love to learn what is the difference between both ;)

Comment: You answer solved my problem with the types not working, though I am also curious as our solutions are similar but mine does not work hahaha.